# beautiful soup not working for specific websites

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have my python code that doesn't work. It should work but I don't know why... it just gives be []

```
url = "https://www.naver.com/"
req = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
res = req.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'html.parser')
keywords = soup.find_all('span', class_='ah_k')

keywords = [each_line.get_text().strip() for each_line in keywords[:20]]
print(keywords)
```

Comment: The site uses Javascript to render content. You can not parse this dynamic content with Beautifulsoup.

Comment: You use Selenium or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to `network Tab` under `XHR` you will get following link which returns `keywords in json format`.You don't need selenium to get the keywords.

> https://www.naver.com/srchrank?frm=main&ag=all&gr=1&ma=-2&si=0&en=0&sp=0

**Code**:

```
import requests
url='https://www.naver.com/srchrank?frm=main&ag=all&gr=1&ma=-2&si=0&en=0&sp=0'
res=requests.get(url).json()
print(res['data'])
for item in res['data']:
    print(item['keyword'])
```

On console the first print will return json data.

```
[{'rank': 1, 'keyword': '챔피언', 'keyword_synonyms': []}, {'rank': 2, 'keyword': '확진자', 'keyword_synonyms': ['코로나 확진자', '추가 확진자', '2차 감염', '우한 폐렴 2차 감염', '6번째 확진자', '확진', '신종코로나', '5번째 확진자', '3번째 확진자', '국내 코로나 확진자', '코로나 바이러스 확진자', '한국 코로나 바이러스 확진자', '평택보건소', '한국 우한폐렴 확진자', '평택 우한폐렴', '우한 전세기', '코로나 확진', '세번째 확진자', '전세기', '국내 우한 폐렴 확진자', '신종코로나 확진자', '우한 폐렴 확진자']}, {'rank': 3, 'keyword': '박한희 변호사', 'keyword_synonyms': []}, {'rank': 4, 'keyword': '서가대', 'keyword_synonyms': []}, {'rank': 5, 'keyword': '박한희', 'keyword_synonyms': []}, {'rank': 6, 'keyword': '500만달러', 'keyword_synonyms': []}, {'rank': 7, 'keyword': '2020 서울가요대상', 'keyword_synonyms': []}, {'rank': 8, 'keyword': '신종코로나바이러스 확진자', 'keyword_synonyms': []}, {'rank': 9, 'keyword': '엄세범', 'keyword_synonyms': []}, {'rank': 10, 'keyword': '판빙빙', 'keyword_synonyms': []}, {'rank': 11, 'keyword': 'who 비상사태', 'keyword_synonyms': []}, {'rank': 12, 'keyword': '임오경', 'keyword_synonyms': []}, {'rank': 13, 'keyword': '수젠텍', 'keyword_synonyms': []}, {'rank': 14, 'keyword': '한해 clip clop', 'keyword_synonyms': []}, {'rank': 15, 'keyword': '장정윤 작가', 'keyword_synonyms': []}, {'rank': 16, 'keyword': '읍참마속', 'keyword_synonyms': []}, {'rank': 17, 'keyword': '재심', 'keyword_synonyms': ['영화 재심']}, {'rank': 18, 'keyword': '아이돌룸', 'keyword_synonyms': []}, {'rank': 19, 'keyword': '조윤선', 'keyword_synonyms': []}, {'rank': 20, 'keyword': '조원태', 'keyword_synonyms': []}]
```

and second print will print all keywords.

```
챔피언
확진자
박한희 변호사
서가대
박한희
500만달러
2020 서울가요대상
신종코로나바이러스 확진자
엄세범
판빙빙
who 비상사태
임오경
수젠텍
한해 clip clop
장정윤 작가
읍참마속
재심
아이돌룸
조윤선
조원태
```

Comment: I can't see the link that you indicated in XHR

Comment: Once you click on XHR you need to press ctrl+R to get to link.

Answer (score 1):

There's a solution that requires pyppeteer and simplified_scrapy to be installed.

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc
from simplified_html.request_render import RequestRender

# req = RequestRender({ 'executablePath': '/Applications/chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome'})
req = RequestRender({ 'executablePath': 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'})
def callback(html,url,extr):
    doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
    keywords = doc.selects('span.ah_k')        
    keywords = [each_line.text for each_line in keywords[:20]]
    print(keywords)
req.get("https://www.naver.com/", callback,selectorOrFunctionOrTimeout='//span[@class="ah_k"]')
```

Result:

```
['포레스트', '장정윤 작가', '나홀로집에3', '박한희', '500만달러', '엄세범', '손승연', '군무원', 'who 비상사태', '소유진 부모님 나이차
이', '맨유 맨시티', '진천', '한송네오텍', '진세연', '염동열', '임종석', '율희', '코미팜', '박한희 변호사', '김경란']
```